# Does solar cell absorb sub-bandgap photons?

Tags: solar-cell, semiconductors, solid-state-devices

My understanding is that although we are taught that solar cells only absorb photons of energy higher than the bandgap of the material, some of the sub-bandgap photons still gets absorbed, which is evident when looking at the absorption coefficient spectra (it is not zero where it is below the bandgap).

First, am I correct on this?
Second, what happens to the sub-bandgap photons that are absorbed?

Comment: I would assume that subbandgap is IR spectrum and is absorbed as heat, can you provide a spectrum graph?

Comment: @crasic Here is the absorption spectra of Silicon. https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/materials/optical-properties-of-silicon
The band gap of Silicon is 1.14 eV at 300 K, which corresponds to a wavelength of 1087 nm. You can see that the absorption coefficient is non zero for wavelength greater than 1087 nm, which means given enough thickness, the sub-bandgap photon will be absorbed.

Comment: @user207787 it would be good to edit your question with the above comment.

Comment: @crasic That's why I said for wavelength "greater" than 1087 nm (which means photons with fewer eV, aka below the bandgap), absorption coefficient is non-zero value, which implies that photons "below the bandgap" will be absorbed given enough thickness of material.

Comment: Yes, most things absorb heat, if you put silicon in an oven it will heat up, it is absorbed as thermal photons .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Physics stack

Comment: *Second, what happens to the sub-bandgap photons that are absorbed?* - like anything else, it gets warm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> absorption coefficient is non-zero value, which implies that photons "below the bandgap" will be absorbed given enough thickness of material

If the photon has less energy than the bandgap, it can't be directly absorbed.  However, there are various other mechanisms by which electrons can combine a photon below the bandgap with another source of energy (a second photon, a phonon, excited state absorption, etc) in order to reach an energy level above the band gap.  Many of these also kick out a new photon at a new wavelength.

Usually these are fairly negligible, especially for low photon flux.  If you look at your chart's units, those absorption depths are in kilometers, so all of these very low probability events would have an extremely long period of time to occur as the photon transmitted the huge volume of material.  You actually do see these effects in things like fiber optics, where a nominally transparent material is used, but over hundreds or thousands of kilometers, all kinds of nonlinear effects happen.